# date_part - gives error when using where clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, group-by, sum

I have a table that looks like this

[image]

I'm wanting to sum the sales and only show sales from 2010.  Using DATE_PART works except when I try to use there WHERE clause

```
SELECT date_part('year', date) AS year, SUM(weekly_sales) as yearly_sales
FROM sales
GROUP BY year
```

[image]

```
SELECT date_part('year', date) AS year, SUM(weekly_sales) as yearly_sales
FROM sales
GROUP BY year
WHERE year = 2010;
```

Is it because the date_part is a double precision?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `WHERE` clause goes *before* the `GROUP BY` clause, and it cannot access column aliases defined in the `SELECT` clause.

You could do:

```
SELECT date_part('year', date) AS year, SUM(weekly_sales) as yearly_sales
FROM sales
WHERE date_part('year', date) = 2010
GROUP BY year
```

Or, more efficiently:

```
SELECT 2010 AS year, SUM(weekly_sales) as yearly_sales
FROM sales
WHERE date >= date '2010-01-01' and date < date '2011-01-01'
```